# MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert date from **MM/DD/YYYY** to **YYYY-MM-DD** using JavaScript

Eg, `7/16/2913` to `2913-07-16T00:00:00+00:00`

Comment: you need to try and show us your effort first!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs) library

```
moment("MM/DD/YYYY", "7/16/2913").format()
//2015-04-14T00:00:00+02:00
```

Comment: I tried the below and it works.. Thanks for your answers.

var r = time.match(/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*\/\s*([0-9]+)\s*\/\s*([0-9]+)(.*)$/);
return r[3]+"-"+r[1]+"-"+r[2]+"T00:00:00+00:00";

Answer (score 1):

`Date` constructor accepts String with format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

```
var dateString='7/16/2913';
var date = new Date(dateString);
console.log(date); // Date 2913-07-15T22:00:00.000Z
```